# How can I do a regex match for first occurrence of any amount of numbers up to a space?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to use `preg_match()` to match the first occurrence of any amount of numbers up until the first space.

```
$var = '2275073540 blah blah blah';
preg_match('/[0-9 ]/', $var, $matches);
```

I want $matches[0] to return `2275073540`.

Comment: What could be the expected output, if you have `dklfjalkfj 4534934daflakjfk 35358948509 daflk` according to your question, it should be 35358948509 as it the only number that is followed by a space. ;) but then that's the not the first occurance of the number.

Comment: Excellent point. And for `$var='abc 123def 456';`, with no space following a number, would the output be empty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
preg_match('/(\d+)/', $var, $matches);
             | ^-|-------------- one or more digits
             ^   ^-------------- capturing group
```

Comment: Note that you don't actually need the parentheses in this.  `$matches[0]` will get the *entire* regex that was matched, and `$matches[1]` get the first group.  Parenthesizing the entire expression might be seen as redundant.  Try `print_r($matches)` with both to see what I mean.

Comment: @ghoti Agreed :) I wrote it thinking of `$matches[1]`, but in this case, it would be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is no PCRE regular expression needed, a simple format scan is enough:

```
sscanf($var, '%f', $number); # $number is 2275073540 now
```

[Demo](http://eval.in/4737)

Comment: +1 but both seem to take 42 sys-calls, on the demo-site. Shouldn't the regex overhead be there?

Comment: Sure there is. Obviously. Why do you count sys-calls, you don't try to find anything in there, do you? :)

Comment: :D My bad. Wouldn't show up in sys-calls. But should show up somewhere, maybe execution-time. Or are regexes optimized that well? On the surface, it is definitely better, but a more quantitative measure, is what I was looking for.

Comment: Well, that can only be fractions of microseconds, I do not see how that measure can be quantitative at all.

Answer (score 2):

This matches anything up to (and not including) the first space:

```
preg_match('/^[^ ]+/', $var, $matches);
```

Though it does not restrict the input to digits.  For that. you'd use:

```
preg_match('/^[[:digit:]]+/', $var, $matches);
```

Or use the short-hand for this character class, as Cthulhu suggested.

Comment: You could use `\s` instead of the space, since what looks like space could be `\t`.

Comment: You could.  I tend to avoid the short-hand.  When the thing representing a space takes more space than a space, it seems better to use a space.  A matter of taste, I think.  :)